# CGMiner and 5830's give my the BSOD and GPU hangs, DEAD threads

Tags: cgminer

I recently switched to CGminer from phoenix from GUIminer. And seem to be having some issues.

System: Windows 7 64bit, x4 5830's

-Timeline-
AMD catalyst: 13.1 
GPUs: 5830x2 7770x1
Miner: CGminer newest stable release 10.5 I think.
Sum: Worked well except for flashing squares on the screen when mining and using the desktop. Saw a post that said update catalyst to 13.2 for no squares.

~~Changelog: updated to 13.2 catalyst, returned the 7770 (money issues)

AMD catalyst: 13.1 
GPUs: 5830x2
Miner: CGminer newest stable release 10.5
Sum: Works well for a few hours (the upgrade to 13.2 also removed the squares), then I either get a DEAD thread for the gpu doing the desktop, or I cannot get windows to return to desktop after it sleeps, or just a good 'ol BSOD.

I was reading around and it said that CGminer makes some binaries on initial run and only initial run. So do those binaries contain info about old 7770 that I removed and now it is conflicting somehow? Should I just reinstall CGminer?

Or do people know of issues with the 13.2 CataContCent?

OP EDIT: test config 1

```
{
"pools" : [
    {
        "url" : "stratum.btcguild.com:3333",
        "user" : "MY USER",
        "pass" : "MY PASS"
    }
],
"intensity" : "d,9,9,9",
"temp-cutoff" : "95,95,95,95",
"temp-overheat" : "85,85,85,85",
"temp-target" : "75,75,75,75",
}
```

What I want my conf to do. Put the three 5830's not doing the desktop balls to the wall. The one I am using for desktop try and do the best it can but do not interfere with desktop.
Turn off any GPU that hits 95C, try to run them all at 75C.

No overclock on any GPU. I do not wish to slow them down or speed them up yet. I just want them to run without crashing my system first. I don't care about fanspeed/noise.

How do I know my 'd' setting will hit GPU0 (my desktop)?

Any other important settings that I removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to lower GPU clock a little bit to let's say 900MHZ or stock, and also make sure that the memory clock is not lower than 300MHZ. After that try to keep an eye on the GPU temperatures as this may be the cause of the sudden BSOD. Also there is a **intensity** parameter, if you keep it as 9 then try to lower it to 7. My config for 5830 looks like this:

```
{
"pools" : [
    {
        "url" : "mint.bitminter.com:8332",
        "user" : "username_workername",
        "pass" : "worker_password"
    }
],
"intensity" : "9,9,9,9",
"gpu-engine" : "0-950,0-950,0-950,0-870",
"gpu-fan" : "0-85,0-85,0-85,0-85",
"gpu-memclock" : "300,300,300,300",
"gpu-powertune" : "20,20,20,20",
"temp-cutoff" : "95,95,95,95",
"temp-overheat" : "85,85,85,85",
"temp-target" : "80,75,75,80",

"algo" : "4way",
"auto-fan" : true,
"auto-gpu" : true,
"expiry" : "120",
"failover-only" : true,
"gpu-threads" : "2",
"log" : "5",
"queue" : "1",
"retry-pause" : "5",
"scan-time" : "60",
"temp-hysteresis" : "3",
"worksize" : "0",

"donation" : "0.00",
"shares" : "0",
"kernel-path" : "/usr/local/bin"
}
```

and works for over a year now :)

Comment: I need to write my own config file first too I guess. I think my problem lies in reinstalling CGminer though. This log file you posted, it is for 4 5830's right? Could you post the entire file?

Comment: What version of Catalyst and CGminer do you have also?

Comment: Could I send you my config file I am about to write here in a few mins and see if it is proper?

Comment: I have edited my answer and included whole file. Yes, this is for 4 graphic cards, if you want less then simply remove additional values.

Catalyst 11.6 (year ago), AMD SDK 2.5. Installing newer catalyst was causing a lot of problems in my case. Newer drivers works fine with 7970 cards but with 5830 I decided to stick with 11.6. Still getting roughly 310mhash

Comment: Well, I guess I cannot PM you. I will post my config in the OP. Look it over if you would.

Comment: If you want you can send me your config, I will take a look.

Comment: I ckecked your config file and...If you don't want to speed them up or slow them down then still add `"gpu-engine" : "0-800,0-800,0-800,0-800",` and then `"auto-gpu" : true,` and `"auto-fan" : true,` You will make sure that in the situation where the graphic cards are getting really hot cgminer has the rights to lower the GPU speed in order to maintain temperature. Setting auto-fan to true will help you to avoid fans being used to much when not needed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7757/discussion-between-bumskeeter-and-sephiroth)